# How to place an icon just after the last character of a multiline textview

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-databinding

I would like to locate a view just after the last word of a (potentially) multi-line TextView.

For example, the TextView might be two lines, with the second line being about half as long as the TextView's width. How do I locate a View just after the last word.

I also want to attach a click listener on that Icon. I am using data binding.
I tried spannabale strings.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, provide some code ,  we cannot able to solve with theses lines , check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this functionality.

Have a look

```
@BindingAdapter("yourTAG")
fun setText(textView: TextView, text: SpannableString?) {
    textView.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    if (!text.isNullOrBlank()) {
        textView.text = text
    }
```

Then in your viewModel create this function

```
private fun getSpannable(text:CharSequence): SpannableString{
        val icon: Drawable = resourcesService.getDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon)

        val spannableString = SpannableString(text)
        val position = spannableString.length-1
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.intrinsicWidth, icon.intrinsicHeight)
        val imageSpan = ImageSpan(icon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)

        spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, position, position +1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                //TODO
            }
        }
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, position, position + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        return spannableString
    }

var myField = getSpannable("Thank you Stackoverflow")
```

In your view

```
app:yourTAG="@{vm.myField}"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    val targetText = "A quick brown fox jumps over \n the lazy dog"
    val text: SpannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(targetText)

    val drawable: Drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)!!
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50)

    //ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE; ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM; ImageSpan.ALIGN_CENTER;
    val imageSpan: ImageSpan = ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)

    val clickSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            Toast.makeText(this@TestActivity, "click icon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    val len: Int = text.length
    text.append("\uFFFC")
    text.setSpan(imageSpan, len, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    text.setSpan(clickSpan, len, text.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

    mViewBinding.tv.highlightColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent)
    mViewBinding.tv.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    mViewBinding.tv.text = text

    mViewBinding.tv.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@TestActivity, "click text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

then you can get :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07QRD.png.)

it's you wish ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).